# How to get height of div in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Happy new year!
I am going to make an animation(change height of div) using @keyframes in CSS.

This is my example code.

```
// html
<div class="care-display">
  <div class="primary">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="secondary">
    ...
  </div>
</div>

//css
.care-display {
  display: flex;
  width: 200%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: animation 0.5s both;
}
@keyframes animation {
  0%    {height: 200px;}   // I want to set height: primary class height, 200px is an example
  100%  {height: 100px;}   // I want to set height: secondary class height, 100px is an example
}
```

I want to get the 'primary' and 'secondary' class height to set 'care-display' height using @keyframes in CSS.
How to get the height of div in CSS and use it in @keyframes?
Anybody, can you help me?

Comment: You can't get the height using CSS, but with JavaScript, it's just [`getComputedStyle(element).height;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)